# HTML: I need to keep all buttons in same line,if the number of buttons exceeds the window width.how do i solve this line issue?

Tags: html, css, tabs

My  project name is Google Module Tab Application.I  am already is working in this project.

here i am faces a problem.i need to keep all buttons in same line,if it exceeds the window width also.but in my project,the buttons cut over and move to the next line.how do i solve this issue

```css
body {
  /*padding:100px;*/
}
.limit {
  width: 1600px;
  overflow: auto;
}
parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 40px;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  /*left:0;*/
  display: inline;
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: large;
  /*border:3px solid #ccc;
                margin:0 10px 0;
                box-shadow: 0 0 2px  #fff inset;*/
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px)rotateX(30deg);
  /*-o-transform:rotateX(30deg);
                -ms-transform:rotateX(30deg);*/
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px)rotateX(30deg);
}
.button:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
.button:active {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 40;
}
.button.drag {
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div class="limit">
    <button data-tab="tab-1" class="button  current ">Car 1</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-2" class="button">Car 2</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-3" class="button">Car 3</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-4" class="button">Car 4</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-5" class="button">Car 5</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-6" class="button">Computer</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-7" class="button">Message</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-8" class="button">Nature</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-9" class="button">Power</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: The wrong ouput snapshot is attached here]

Comment: Have you tried `overflow-x: auto` on the parent element (`.limit`) ?

Comment: yeah. i am tried. then i changed the overflow:auto

Comment: In case you can use make use bootstrap CSS, you have the justified menu bar for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an alternative to using a width size - the usage of flex:

```html
 <style>
    body
    {
    /*padding:100px;*/
    }
    .limit
    {
    width:1600px;
     display:flex;
     flex-wrap:nowrap;
    }
    parent {
            position:relative;
            margin: 20px;
            width: 800px;
            height: 40px;

        }
    .button {
            position:relative;
            /*left:0;*/
            display: inline-flex;
            width: 200px;
            height: 75px;
            background-color:lightgray;
            font-size:large;
            /*border:3px solid #ccc;
            margin:0 10px 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px  #fff inset;*/
            -webkit-transform: perspective(100px)rotateX(30deg);
            /*-o-transform:rotateX(30deg);
            -ms-transform:rotateX(30deg);*/
            -moz-transform: perspective(100px)rotateX(30deg);
            }
   .button:hover { 
    cursor: default;
  }
   .button:active 
  {
    cursor:move;
    z-index:40;
  }
  .button.drag {
     z-index: 99; 
     background-color:orange;
  }

</style>
<body>
<div id="parent" class="parent">
<div class="limit">
<button data-tab="tab-1" class="button  current " >Car 1</button>
<button data-tab="tab-2" class="button">Car 2</button>
<button data-tab="tab-3" class="button">Car 3</button>
<button data-tab="tab-4" class="button">Car 4</button>
<button data-tab="tab-5" class="button">Car 5</button>
<button data-tab="tab-6" class="button">Computer</button>
<button data-tab="tab-7" class="button">Message</button>
<button data-tab="tab-8" class="button">Nature</button>
<button data-tab="tab-9" class="button">Power</button>
</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: The flex solution is great when you don't need the old Internet Explorer bad friend... IN that case is good.

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of giving width in pixel try to give width in %**.

```css
body {
  /*padding:100px;*/
}
.limit {
  width: 1600px;
  overflow: auto;
}
parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 40px;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  /*left:0;*/
  display: inline;
  width: 8%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: large;
  /*border:3px solid #ccc;
  margin:0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px  #fff inset;*/
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px)rotateX(30deg);
  /*-o-transform:rotateX(30deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateX(30deg);*/
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px)rotateX(30deg);
}
.button:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
.button:active {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 40;
}
.button.drag {
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div class="limit">
    <button data-tab="tab-1" class="button  current ">Car 1</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-2" class="button">Car 2</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-3" class="button">Car 3</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-4" class="button">Car 4</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-5" class="button">Car 5</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-6" class="button">Computer</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-7" class="button">Message</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-8" class="button">Nature</button>
    <button data-tab="tab-9" class="button">Power</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will be helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Use same as it is your code and just give`white-space: nowrap;` property to `.limit` class, that property wont allow wrap so automatically scroll will come.

Hope this solution solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

just add
display: inline-flex;
to the .limit class

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: this is the answer